# error reading in PHP

Tags: php

Yes I believe I have this done but I am getting a message that is saying  Parse error: parse error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\contactform.php on line 106. I look down on that line.The only think I can think of is that the else, elseif and if are wrong i been trying to switch them around to see if that makes a different. But nothing so far.

```
    </style>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if (trim($_POST['name'])==""){
           $strMessage="Please enter your name!";
           showForm($strMessage);
        } elseif (isset($_POST['submit'])){
               if (trim($_POST['email'])==""){
                  $strMessage="Please enter your email!";
                  showForm($strMessage);
               }
               if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                  if (trim($_POST['username'])==""){
                      $strMessage="Please enter your username!";
                      showForm($strMessage);
                  } elseif ($_POST['pword1'] != $_POST['pword2']) {
                      $_POST['pword1'] = NULL;  // Reset the values of pword1 so it is not in the form
                      $_POST['pword2'] = NULL;  // Reset the values of pword2 so it is not in the form
                      $strMessage="Passwords do not match!";
                      showForm($strMessage);
                  } elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['pword1']))<=3){
                      $strMessage="Your password must be at least 4 characters long!";
                      showForm($strMessage);
                  } else {
                      $strMessage="Thank you, your information has been submitted. Below is the       information you sent:";
                      $strMessageBody.="Name: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']))."<br />";
                      $strMessageBody.="E-mail: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']))."<br />";
                      $strMessageBody.="UserName: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['username']))."<br />";
                      $strMessageBody.="Password: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['pword1']))."<br />";
                      $strMessageBody.="Re-enter Password: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['pword2']))."<br  />";
                      echo "<h1>".$strMessage."</h1>";
                      echo $strMessageBody;
                   }
               } else {
                   $strMessage= "Please fill out the form below to send your information:";
                   showForm($strMessage);
               }
            }
      ?>
   </div>
    </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: You should learn to indent better. (use soft tabs for indentation) It's hard to read your code. You may have a missing brace some where. Indent your code properly; it helps other developers in a team environment and even if you're by yourself, it'll still help you out.

Comment: You are missing a closing brace. And programming isn't done by switching things around randomly.

Comment: What's that `.` before the `else` on line 87?

Comment: Try to use [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) - you will know what is a code auto-formatting, code-completion and smart syntax checks.

Comment: You're checking `isset($_POST['submit'])` a lot more than necessary. Once should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. You have been repeating the "if (isset($_POST['submit'])){" two times too many!

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (trim($_POST['name'])==""){
    $strMessage="Please enter your name!";
    showForm($strMessage);
  } elseif (trim($_POST['email'])==""){
      $strMessage="Please enter your email!";
    showForm($strMessage);
  } elseif (trim($_POST['username'])==""){
    $strMessage="Please enter your username!";
    showForm($strMessage);
  } elseif ($_POST['pword1'] != $_POST['pword2']) {
    $_POST['pword1'] = NULL;  // Reset the values of pword1 so it is not in the form
    $_POST['pword2'] = NULL;  // Reset the values of pword2 so it is not in the form
    $strMessage="Passwords do not match!";
    showForm($strMessage);
  } elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['pword1']))<=3){
    $strMessage="Your password must be at least 4 characters long!";
    showForm($strMessage);
  } else {
    $strMessage="Thank you, your information has been submitted. Below is the       information you sent:";
    $strMessageBody.="Name: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']))."<br />";
    $strMessageBody.="E-mail: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']))."<br />";
    $strMessageBody.="UserName: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['username']))."<br />";
    $strMessageBody.="Password: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['pword1']))."<br />";
    $strMessageBody.="Re-enter Password: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['pword2']))."<br  />";
    echo "<h1>".$strMessage."</h1>";
    echo $strMessageBody;
  }
} else {
  $strMessage= "Please fill out the form below to send your information:";
  showForm($strMessage);
}
```

Comment: I started this "project" for a minute then bailed out. +1 for effort, but check your `elsif`s, PHP needs `elseif`

Comment: @Wesley Tnx! `elsif`s changed into `elseif`s

Answer (score 2):

one closing } is missing. the only question is where? if you put it before ?> the parse error will disappear, but i'm not sure this is apropieate place. depends on your difficult logic.

Comment: If you look at the code a little closer (not easy I know) you will see that most likely, with some interpretation of the code itself, the problem lies a little deeper (see my answer).